# РИА "Новости", РИА Новости или "РИА Новости"?

Tags: пунктуация

Почему на "Грамоте.ру" и в других справках дают рекомендацию писать РИА "Новости"? При том что официальное название - Российское агентство международной информации «РИА Новости» (ФГУП РАМИ «РИА Новости»), а само агентство хочет, чтобы писали так - РИА Новости.

Какой из трех вариантов все-таки правильный? Может, все-таки "РИА Новости"? Например, в тексте: Как сообщило "РИА Новости"...

Comment: Простите, но флуд должен быть отмечен.)))
Будете хорошо себя вести - расскажу, как я это сделал. 
Сразу говорю, это было первый раз - на эту идею вы же меня и натолкнули своими предыдущими претензиями.

Comment: Без проблем, дружище бегемотус! На форуме должен быть порядок! Все слышали?

Answer (score 2):

"В миру" надо было бы писать РИА "Новости", мне кажется, так как "Новости" - это название, а РИА - аббревиатура, расшифровка которой состоит из слов нарицательных.

Но есть и юридическое понятие: в уставе фирмы указывается полное и сокращенное название и здесь, вообще говоря, к названию могут быть отнесены любые слова и буквы.

> - Не может быть такого имени Посторонним В.
> - Может, потому что дедушку так звали

Железная логика!

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае названием является только слово "Новости" — оно и берется в кавычки. РИА — это Российское Информационное Агентство, а оно ни разу в кавычки не берется.

Comment: Как не берется, когда в официальном названии оно в кавычках, вместе со словом Новости. ФГУП РАМИ «РИА Новости». Вот я и спрашиваю, можно ли писать так: Как сообщило "РИА Новости"...

Comment: Официальное название не содержит аббревиатур.Они могут быть в кратком, но оно гораздо короче. Просто РИА "Новости". Как там стоят кавычки - и есть ли они - это уже надо смотреть в уставе.

Answer (score 0):

> Почему на "Грамоте.ру" и в других справках дают рекомендацию писать РИА "Новости"?

На Грамоте и других справках исходят из орфографических правил и рекомендаций, которым реальные названия не всегда следуют. Проверять закрепленное Уставом написание в задачу справок не входит

> При том что официальное название - Российское агентство международной информации «РИА Новости» (ФГУП РАМИ «РИА Новости»),

Официальное (полное) название не содержит аббревиатур, там все слова от "федерального" до "информации" даны полностью. Сокращенного варианта не знаю, скорее всего "РИА Новости".

> а само агентство хочет, чтобы писали так - РИА Новости.

Я их понимаю. Причем в тексте этот вариант следует забирать в кавычки, а для подписи под заметками вполне возможно и без них.

> Какой из трех вариантов все-таки правильный?

А "из трёх" - это из каких?! Вижу два - "Новости" в кавычках и без.

> Может, все-таки "РИА Новости"?   Например, в тексте: Как сообщило "РИА Новости"...

Да, в тексте - именно так.

ЗЫ Вариант "РИА Новости" (в кавычках и без них) охначает, что аббревиатура РИА потеряла самостоятельное значение и стала частью названия.